# How to clear the content of a String which has already been used in C Programming?

Tags: c, string, null

I want to reuse the same string which I have created and store other content. The program does not accept the second-time Character String input showing an error. I tried to assign the variable i.e. string1[] = NULL, but it didn't work.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h
    
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        char string1[15];
        printf("\n\n\n\nEnter a string containing only alphabets\n: ");
        scanf("%[a-z]", string1);
        printf("%s", string1);
        printf("\nEnter another string that contains characters other than the alphabets: ");
        scanf("%[^a-z]", string1);
        printf("%s\n End of the program!!!\n\n", string1);
        return 0;
    }
```

The output is as below...

```
Enter a string containing only alphabets
asdf
asdf.  
Enter another string that contains characters other than the alphabets: 12345
1235       
1235          //The program here keeps on accepting numbers and aborts it only when I type exit...
1235     

exit

12345
1235
1235
1235

 End of the program!!!

Abort trap: 6
```

Also, what is the meaning of the "Abort trap: 6" issued by the compiler?

Comment: You can't assign `NULL` to that array, it's not a pointer like that. You can clear it with `bzero()` or `memset()` or just `string1[0] = 0`.

Comment: Don't forget to check the return values of `scanf` to be sure it actually did something.

Comment: The error message is not issued by the compiler but by the runtime environment of your program.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
scanf("%[^a-z]", string1);
```

will scan anything, even the newline character, it would stop only when you type any lowercase letter. Try typing something that include letters at the end:

```
   123124ahhh!
```

it would print 123124 and you wouldn't need to exit.

But if you want to read the string once you press enter, change the line to:

```
scanf("%[^a-z\n]", string1);
```

However, there is always a '\n' after each string entering that will be left for the next reading and will probably cause trouble... you can get rid of that '\n' by adding a %*c after the scanfs, which stands for "dispose the next char".

```
 scanf("%[^a-z]%*c", string1);
```

and

```
 scanf("%[^a-z\n]%*c", string1);
```

Comment: This will probably read nothing, as the next character to be read is the newline at the end of the first line.